# Node.js events and eventhandler with rest parameters

Tags: node.js, events, eventhandler

I am using this to load my eventHandlers and I thought the ...args would pass all arguments but it is only passing the first I think. I have ince found out that the tutorial I was using is an early release maybe there is a change in they way you achieve this?

```
fs.readdir('./events/', (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {                                                                                                                                                                                const eventHandler = require(`./events/${file}`)
    const eventName = file.split('.')[0]
    client.on(eventName, (...args) => eventHandler(client, ...args))
  })
})
```

Comment: So you basically want to pass any and all arguments supplied at an event emit (such as `client.emit('some name',arg1,agr2)` ) to your eventHandler, right?

Comment: Anuj Pancholi exactly I could have typed it all out if full but this seemed the easier why to add more handlers

Answer (score 0):

It depends if `client.on` callback is passed more than one arg, and if `eventHandler` takes more than one arg.

Use `console.log(...args)` in each place to see what is passed in.